# Uncaught TypeError: object is not iterable -->using context with reducer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-context

I am learning to use useContext and useReducer together but am getting an error I haven't managed to figure out:

> Uncaught TypeError: object is not iterable (cannot read property Symbol(Symbol.iterator))

It occurred after destructuring the context inside MealItemForm.js. I tried setting default value in createContext, importing with and without curly braces etc. I am trying to dispatch the function inside children component. Any idea?

MealItemForm.js

```
import React,{useContext} from 'react';
import MeatContext from '../store/meat-context';
import Input from './Input';
import styles from "./MealItemForm.module.css"

function MealItemForm(props) {
  
  const [meatState,dispatchMeatState]=useContext(MeatContext)
  const handleClick=(event)=>{
event.preventDefault();

  }  
  
  return (
      <form className={styles.form}>
          <Input/>
          <button onClick={handleClick}>+ Add</button>
      </form>
  );
}

export default MealItemForm;
```

meat-context.js

```
import React,{useReducer,useState} from 'react';


const MeatContext = React.createContext({meatState:[]});

export function MeatContextProvider(props) {
  const meatReducer = (state, action) => {
    if (action.type === 'ADD_MEAT') {
      return [...meatState];
    }

    return {  };
  };
  
  const [meatState, dispatchMeatState] = useReducer(meatReducer,
    [

    ]
  );
  return (
<MeatContext.Provider value={{meatState:meatState,dispatchMeatState:dispatchMeatState}}>
  {props.children}
</MeatContext.Provider>
  );

  
}
export default MeatContext
```

Comment: Use object destructuring instead,  `const { meatState, dispatchMeatState } = useContext(MeatContext)`

Comment: thanks, that makes it solved

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value provided to `Context` is an object

```js
{meatState:meatState,dispatchMeatState:dispatchMeatState}
```

But you're using array destructuring while getting the values

```js
const [meatState, dispatchMeatState ] = useContext(MeatContext)
```

Using object destructuring should solve it,

```js
const { meatState, dispatchMeatState } = useContext(MeatContext)
```

Answer (score 0):

Restructuring with {object} instead of [array] solves the issue